# EntityFrameWork Core 5.0 tries to drops dbset from raw queries which do not exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration, ef-core-5.0

I created DbSets for my Raw Queries or StoredProcs in my dbcontext and used `modelBuilder.Entity<_Entity>().HasNoKey().ToView(null)` under OnModelCreating. I use them in my controller like below:

```
_context._RTable.FromSqlRaw("exec sp_Run @thiscasenumber", casenumber).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

It used to work fine on EF Core 3.1.
I recently upgraded my solution to 5.0. now when I try to do add-migration, the first time it does the job and everything works fine, but without making any change, after update-database, when I run add-migration again, it creates a migration and tries to delete these non-existing entities. `migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "_RTable");`

Is there any way to prevent EF from dropping these "Tables" which do not exist?

Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing and cannot find a solution. Good to hear I'm not alone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085351/net-5-0-ef-migrations-adding-stored-proc-models-to-modelsnapshot

Comment: I tried it on a new project and it didn't do the same behavior! I was hoping to find a way to prevent ef core from dropping the columns, but so far no luck... I may create a new project and move everything there manually to see how it goes ...

Answer (score 0):

This is due to breaking changes in `.ToView(null)` behavior in .NET 5.

Based on [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#toview) you should be using `.ToTable("ViewName", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations())` to exclude enity set from migration.