# .net 5.0 EF migrations adding stored proc models to ModelSnapshot

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-5.0

I recently upgraded to .net 5.0 and I use entity framework. I edited a database model by adding an extra field and ran my normal script in powershell

```
dotnet ef migrations add mig_name
```

Since the C# upgrade though the upgrade script is trying to add all my Keyless models that I use for Stored Procs to the ModelSnapshot file. And what that means is that it tries to then drop these tables from the database even though they don't exist.

```
 protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "SimpleStoredProc");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "StoredProc2");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "StoredProc3");
       }
```

etc.

I have read the [latest article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) on the subject and tried adding [Keyless] above my model definitions. This didn't fix it.

I can manually edit the ModelSnapshot file and edit out all the Keyless tables, but when I ran another migration script they are all put back there.

My DbContext file looks like

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {         
          
            modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleStoredProc>(eb => { eb.HasNoKey(); eb.ToView(null); });
        }
```

I've spent a day on this! Driving me mad. Has anyone else upgraded from Net core 3.1 to .net 5.0 and had problems with EF migrations?

Comment: Please, check your versions. There's no .NET Core 3.1, C# 5.0 is way older than .NET Core. What is your runtime and version and what is the version of EF?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Sorry, I did get a bit mixed up. I meant the new .net 5.0. And I upgraded from net core 3.1. Thanks

Comment: You should change your question and tags to focus on the correct issue. Your issue seems to be a migration from EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.x to 5.0.0. You seem to have no issues with the runtime or programming language. You should file an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore